# Div overlap another div

Tags: css

I have an issue I really can't figure out.

My login div overlapping my menu when my screen solution is smaller than XX. (found out when i changed from 21" to 15".)

I godt an menu witch seems to stay where it's placed, but the login box under is overlapping.

I got my css here:

```
/*******************
FONTS
*******************/

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

/*******************
SELECTION STYLING
*******************/

::selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f676b2; /* Safari */
}
::-moz-selection {
    color: #fff;
    background: #f676b2; /* Firefox */
}

/*******************
BODY STYLING
*******************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

/*******************
TOPBAR
*******************/
#topbar { 
   list-style: none;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   letter-spacing: -0.5px; 
   font-size: 13px;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;
   width: 100%; 
   height: 30px;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #787878), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383));
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #787878 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%);
   background-color:#5f5f5f;

    /*-moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;*/

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b;
}

#wrapper1 {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Center wrapper perfectly */
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}

/*
.gradient {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -300px;

    background: url(../img/gradient.png) no-repeat;
}
*/

.gradient {
    /* Center Positioning */
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    margin-top: -300px;

    /* Fallback */ 
    background-image: url(../img/gradient.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 

    /* CSS3 Gradient */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(213,246,255,1)), to(rgba(213,246,255,0)));
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 40% 40%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
    background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
    background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
}

/*******************
MENU
*******************/
#menu { 
   margin: 40px 0; 
   list-style: none;
   font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
   letter-spacing: -0.5px; 
   font-size: 13px;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px 3px #202020;
   width: 980px; 
   height: 34px;

    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b;
}

#menu li { 
   display: block; 
   float: left; 
   border-right: 1px solid #5d5d5d; 
   border-left: 1px solid #929292; 
   width: 105px; 
   height: 34px; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #575757; 
   border-top: 1px solid #797979;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #787878), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383));
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #787878 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%);
   background-color:#5f5f5f;
}

#menu li:not(:last-child):hover {
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
   background-color:#383838;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px 5px #535353;
}

#menu li:not(:last-child):active {
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #3F3F3F), color-stop(0.5, #383838), color-stop(0.51, #434343), color-stop(1, #555555));
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #3F3F3F 0%, #383838 50%, #434343 51%, #555555 100% );
   background-color:#383838;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px 2px #000;
}

#menu li a { 
   color: white; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   text-align: center; 
   display: block; 
   line-height: 34px; 
   outline: none; 
}

#menu form input { 
   width: 76px; 
   height: 20px; 
   margin-left: 9px; 
   margin-top: 8px; 
   border: none; 
   padding-left: 20px; 
   padding-right: 10px; 
   color: #eee;

    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
   background-image: url("../img/magnifier.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #747474), color-stop(0.5, #6E6E6E), color-stop(0.51, #7E7E7E), color-stop(1, #8D8D8D));
   background-image: url("../img/magnifier.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #747474 0%, #6E6E6E 50%, #7E7E7E 51%, #8D8D8D 100%);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-color: #6E6E6E;

    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 1px 1px #363636;
}

#menu li:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;

   border-left: none;
}


#menu li:first-child a img {
   vertical-align: middle; 
   margin-top: -2px;
}

#menu li:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;

   border-right: none;
   width: 124px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes showMenu {
    from { opacity: 0; top: -20px; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}

#menu {
     -webkit-animation: showMenu 1s; 
   position: relative;
}

/*******************
LOGIN FORM
*******************/

.login-form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:5;

    background: #f3f3f3;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

/*******************
HEADER
*******************/

.login-form .header {
    padding: 40px 30px 30px 30px;
}

.login-form .header h1 {
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height:34px;
    color: #414848;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(256,256,256,1.0);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-form .header span {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: #678889;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(256,256,256,1.0);
}

/*******************
CONTENT
*******************/

.login-form .content1 {
    padding: 0 30px 25px 30px;
}

/* Input field */
.login-form .content1 .input {
    width: 188px;
    padding: 15px 25px;

    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #9d9e9e;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(256,256,256,1.0);

    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
}

/* Second input field */
.login-form .content1 .password, .login-form .content .pass-icon {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.login-form .content1 .input:hover {
    background: #dfe9ec;
    color: #414848;
}

.login-form .content1 .input:focus {
    background: #dfe9ec;
    color: #414848;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

.user-icon, .pass-icon {
    width: 46px;
    height: 47px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    z-index: 3;

    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

.user-icon {
    top:147px; /* Positioning fix for slide-in, got lazy to think up of simpler method. */
    background: rgba(65,72,72,0.75) url(../img/user-icon.png) no-repeat center; 
}

.pass-icon {
    top:221px;
    background: rgba(65,72,72,0.75) url(../img/pass-icon.png) no-repeat center;
}

/* Animation */
.input, .user-icon, .pass-icon, .button, .register {
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*******************
FOOTER
*******************/

.login-form .footer {
    padding: 25px 30px 40px 30px;
    overflow: auto;

    background: #d4dedf;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

/* Login button */
.login-form .footer .button {
    float:left;
    padding: 11px 25px;

    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);

    background: #56c2e1;
    border: 1px solid #46b3d3;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
}

.login-form .footer .button:hover {
    background: #3f9db8;
    border: 1px solid rgba(256,256,256,0.75);

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.login-form .footer .button:focus {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;

    background: #56c2e1;

    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px rgba(256,256,256,0.75);
}

/* Register button 
.login-form .footer .register {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-right: 20px;

    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #414848;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 rgba(256,256,256,0.5);
}

.login-form .footer .register:hover {
    color: #3f9db8;
}

.login-form .footer .register:focus {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1px;
}*/
```

I'm not a genius in CSS, so im glad to see people helps in here, and so damn fast generally!
Thank you! :-)

Comment: share you HTML pls, and if you can create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/c98GT/

Comment: you want login form to be under menu ?

Comment: Yes, and it ovetlaps, as you probaly can see. :-)

Comment: Wrapper1 should be relative and add clear:both in wrapper1 css

Comment: you see that? a fiddle makes people to rip your problem :D

Comment: @Atul - Works, but the "glow" behind the loginbox still overlaps, and the box is right under. Ill like it to be like 20px under :-)

Comment: Two points: 1. I dont get which glow you are talking about. 2. By saying that its not 20px under its showing you are not putting much effort by yourself. :) Just use margin-top as simple is that. Stackoverflow is the place where you show your efforts first and then expect people to help you.  Its not the place where people should code for you :) Also suggest you to http://www.w3schools.com/css/ and understand CSS.. Happy coding :)

Comment: 1: Gradiant = Fixed (by myself btw)
2: I did not really understand how the sake it was up there. If I start using margin-top, I'll get the same problem.. Simple.
- But all fine now! You too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit `#wrapper1` like this:

```
#wrapper1 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 145px;   /* or more  */
margin-left: -150px;
}
```

and your gradient like this:

```
.gradient {
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
top: 145px;   /* as the top of wrapper */
margin-left: -300px;
margin-top: 0px;
background-image: url(../img/gradient.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(rgba(213,246,255,1)), to(rgba(213,246,255,0)));
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 40% 40%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(50% 50%, 50% 50%, rgba(213,246,255,1), rgba(213,246,255,0));
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/c98GT/3/)

## Update:

as the @Atul you can use `position:relative` for `#wrapper1` too. look at this code:

```
#wrapper1 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
width: 300px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -150px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/c98GT/5/)

Comment: Increasing value of top isnt good. Ideally, position of wrapper1 should be relative and clear:both should be added in wrapper1

Comment: That helps, but the glow is still at the overlap stadium

Comment: I don't see any problem in Fiddle buddy, if your problem is in your website just share the link

Answer (score 0):

Since you position your inlogbox absolute it will overlap the menu at some point. (When the window size is smaller than the height of the menu and inlogbox together).

The only thing you can do is position your inlogbox static.

Therefor, change:

```
#wrapper1 {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* Center wrapper perfectly */
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -200px;
}
```

To:

```
#wrapper1 {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:300;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The inlogbox will [then be under the menu](http://jsfiddle.net/c98GT/4/) . If you want extra space between the menu and inlogbox, simply add a `margin-top` to the inlogbox.

Comment: The two pictures who should come out from the side is shown static on left side of the screen.